# Python: String concatenation working differently inside for loop

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, concatenation

I have a NumPy array containing a list which contains strings of various lengths:

```
arr = np.array(["abcd", "abcdef", "ab"])
```

I'm trying to loop through the strings in order to pad them to a constant length. If i do it one at a time, like so:

```
new_len = 10

left_pad = divmod(new_len - len(arr[0]),2)[0]
right_pad = left_pad + divmod(new_len - len(arr[0]),2)[1]

abcd = arr[0].join(["_"*left_pad, "_"*right_pad])
```

I get my desired output of:

```
'___abcd___'
```

But if I try doing it in a loop, like so:

```
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    left_pad = divmod(new_len - len(arr[i]),2)[0]
    right_pad = left_pad + divmod(new_len - len(arr[i]),2)[1]
    arr[i] = arr[i].join(["_"*left_pad, "_"*right_pad])
```

I get this different output:

```
array(['___abc', '__abcd', '____ab'], dtype='<U6')
```

I'd like to understand why the behaviour is different in these two cases, and how I can get the desired output with a loop. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Please always include the [tag:numpy] tag when asking NumPy questions. Python itself has [an `array` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array) that is quite different from these arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to define your array as an array of objects like in the example bellow:

```
arr = np.array(["abcd", "abcdef", "ab"], dtype='object')
```

According to the output of your example you've created an array of char with length of 6 (dtype='<U6')

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate further as daniboy000 perfectly mentioned, <U6 means, the longest string of the `np.arr` declared here has the length of 6. So, for testing you can use `dtype="<U11"` also, but for a general use case `dtype="object"` is more appropriate.

Also, I wanted to add it just as a comment but currently, I do not match the required reputation.